# @computed and @tracked in Ember.js

Tags: ember.js

Currently, I am working on Octanify Components in Ember.js. I can't figure out the difference between using @computed and @tracked. It's similar, but sometimes I found a problem.

```
@computed
get departments() {
  return this.store.query('department', { per_page: 1 });
}
```

In this case, removing @computed puts you in an infinity cycle.
What's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@computed` here (in octane) is functioning *similarly* to `@cached`, in that it protects you from the content of the getter re-running every time `departments` is accessed (because getters are basically methods that don't need parenthesis (and getters are called MethodDefinition in most Abstract Syntax Trees (fun fact!)))

when you remove `@computed`, `this.store.query(...)` is invoked on *every access*.

to protect against this, you can throw `@cached` on there `import { cached } from '@glimmer/tracking'` (available in `ember-source@4.1+` or earlier via [polyfill](https://github.com/ember-polyfills/ember-cached-decorator-polyfill))

`@tracked`, on the other hand, is only for your *root* state, which is properties you'd want to mutate or *track changes to* and have those changes (and data derived from them) reflected in the UI.

For example:

```
export default class Foo extends Component {
  @tracked num = 0;

  @tracked localCopy = this.args.passedIn;
}
```

these values can be set via `this.num = 2;`, and `this.localCopy = 'new value';` (for example)

---

there are also libraries that help out with this problem, specifically with ember-data (which I assume is what is providing the `this.store`). For example: https://github.com/NullVoxPopuli/ember-data-resources/#query

you code would become:

```
import { query } from 'ember-data-resources';

export default class MyComponent extends Component {
  departments = query(this, 'departments', () => ({ per_page: 1 }));
}
```

```
Available properties:
 - {{this.blog.records}}
 - {{this.blog.error}}
 - {{this.blog.isLoading}}
 - {{this.blog.isSuccess}}
 - {{this.blog.isError}}
 - {{this.blog.hasRun}}

Available methods:
 - <button {{on 'click' this.blog.retry}}>Retry</button>
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain more about Octane? https://guides.emberjs.com/release/upgrading/current-edition/glimmer-components/ explains a lot about Octane. But I want to know more about glimmer object and native classes.

Comment: happy to answer more stack overflow questions :D